# image not showing while giving random string after image source name

Tags: html, xhtml, html-parsing

For an image I gave src attribute as

```
src="http://www.somedomain.com:80/app/top_level_includes/images/logo.gif?65463454"
```

But it didn't get any image.
I am giving this random number to avoid caching. 
One more note : Here the image path domain and my site domain are different.

Comment: Could it be that the image is gone, and you're only seeing the file without `?xxxxxx` because of caching?

Comment: Image is there in the folder. But when i remove the '?xxxxx' it will display image. You can check in firebug also, there if you remove the '?xxxxx' then it will show the image

Comment: Ok, in that case: do you have a link to the image? I'm assuming it's not hosted on "somedomain.com", so I can't see what you're seeing :)